# How to route to a path/file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, public

I have a subdomain that need to point to a folder inside the public folder.

I would be searching for something like this:

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new(CONFIG[:short_domain]) do
  match '/:id' => '/path/to/folder/with/files/:id'
end
```

There is any build in way? Or a gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the routing as-is and use [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file), but there may well be a cleaner way that doesn't involve writing an (admittedly trivial) action. (Or handle it at a higher level, depending on what server you're using, I suppose.)

Comment: Yea, I wanted to avoid using something like that.
I guess the other option is using a RewriteRule in the production server.